# A question in Abstract Algebra about Homomorphism from R to Z

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question in Abstract Algebra, I tried to solve it but without any success.
The question is: prove that the only group homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}^\times \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: If by $\;R,Z\;$ you mean the reals and the integers, then multiplicatively $\;\Bbb R\;$ is **not** a group, but $\;\Bbb R^*:=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\;$ is. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$. If $\phi(a)=b$, what shall $\phi(a^{1/n})$ be?

Comment: it will be b/n and it may not be in Z, is this the proof?

Comment: Yes, that is the proof.  Let $\phi(a)=b$. For any $n$, if $\phi(a^{1/n})=c$, then $c+c+\cdots +c=b$ ($c$ has been added to itself $n$ times). But if $b\ne 0$, there is an $n$ for which there is no such $c$.  The end. In more technical language, $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a divisible group. Instead of working with $n$-th roots, we could work with iterated square roots. Same argument.